# Disable / Enable Functions via Compiler Argument

Tags: actionscript-3

). You know, in C++, C# and other educated languages, we got the chance to enable/disable the availability of some code in a certain class via compiler arguments. Take #if and #endif for example. You give an argument to the compiler, for example PROJECT_TDD_MODE, when a certain bunch of function would exist in the final code, but without defining that, or defining it as FALSE, the code would not exist in the compiled result.

Why don't we have something like this in AS3? ::- (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional compilation is available in Actionscript too. Take a look at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html